# Unsolicited SMS from Facebook

Tags: facebook

I got the following SMS from number 32665 (FBOOK):

> "Confirmed! To edit SMS preferences go to m.facebook.com/settings. To turn off all SMS messages reply stop. Reply help for other option. SMS charges may apply"

I'm worried someone hacked into my account, since I did not do anything in the last weeks that would generate this message.
I think this SMS means somebody enters a confirmation code in a new deviced to be recognized. For example, the message is generated in the [following simple hack](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/15651/digital-id/facebook-hacked-with-an-sms-excellent-the-bug-management.html). That hack which was fixed quickly.

Is there a way I can find out why this SMS was sent? Sadly, the activity log doesn't show security-related actions (such as logins). I didn't see any unknown devices under "Security > Your Browsers and Apps", but someone could potentially delete himself after checking something out.
I had login notifications & login alerts on all the time.

Comment: This is more of a question for Facebook support.

Answer (score 1):

If you had notification alerts on, you would receive the login alert over SMS / E-mail (depends on you what have you chosen).

And if you suspect that someone hacked into your account immediately change your password.

Now, to answer your question:

> "Is there **a way** I can see why this SMS was sent?"

There are no results for this question and I can't help you with this but I guess someone really accessed your account.  And argument for being suspicious right now is the activity/behaviour you described.

It's also recommended to enable the SMS alert when new device connects. Maybe the Facebook security tips are known to you already, but I prefer you to check them again. [LINK](https://www.facebook.com/help/379220725465972)

Also verify your email related to the FB account. An attacker could gain access by using your hacked email...

> Sadly, the activity log doesn't show things like that. I didn't see
>   any unknown devices under Security > Your Browsers and Apps, but
>   someone could potentially delete himself. I had login notifications &
>   login alerts on all the time.

SMS or Email alerts? by hacking your email the attacker could delete logs.